# Problema de permissão fazendo upload de arquivos

Tags: php, yii

Criei um cadastro de produtos que contém uma função de *upload* de imagens.
A operação está sendo feita normalmente, o arquivo vai pra pasta determinada, e pelo sistema até consigo visualizar a imagem da qual eu fiz o *upload*.

O problema é na hora de alterar, porque quando eu faço o *upload* pelo sistema, o arquivo vai com restrições de acesso.

> PS: Somente quando faço *upload* pelo sistema, porque quando eu copio o arquivo normalmente pelo *windows*, tudo fica correto e não dá problema em nada.

Segue abaixo o método de *upload*:

```
public static function uploadFile($file, $nomeDocumento, $diretorio, $extValidas = array()) {
    $ext = pathinfo ( $file['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION );

    try {

        if (!isset ( $file['error'] ) || is_array( $file['error'] )) {
            throw new RuntimeException( 'Parâmetros Inválidos.' );
        }

        switch ($file['error']){
            case UPLOAD_ERR_OK :
                break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE :
                throw new RuntimeException( 'Nenhum arquivo Enviado.' );

            /*
             * case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
             * case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
             * throw new RuntimeException('Limite de tamanho de arquivo excedido.');
             */

            default :
                throw new RuntimeException( 'Erro Desconhecido' );
        }

        // if ($file['size'] > 1000000) { throw new RuntimeException('Limite de tamanho de arquivo excedido.'); }

        if (!in_array( $ext, $extValidas )){
            throw new RuntimeException( "Formato de arquivo inválido\nArquivos permitidos: " . implode( ', ', array( 'pdf', 'PDF', 'jpg', 'JPG', 'png', 'PNG', 'jpeg', 'JPEG')));
        }

        if (!move_uploaded_file( $file['tmp_name'], $diretorio . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $nomeDocumento.'.'.$ext)) {
            throw new RuntimeException ( 'Failed to move uploaded file.' );
        }

        return true;
    } catch ( RuntimeException $e ) {
        return $e->getMessage ();
    }
}
```

> P.S.: Estou usando YiiFramework, e salvando os arquivos dentro de: **protected/data/produtos/**.

Comment: Veja as permissões da pasta que esta recebendo os arquivos! Para vc esta normal pq é o proprietário! Veja as demais que deve resolver!

Comment: eu verifiquei e a permissão da pasta está ok, mas o problema persiste em acontecer